# Verificar se uma data é válida

Tags: c#

Estou com um trabalho de faculdade no qual preciso verificar se uma data é válida mas não posso utilizar as classe ***DateTime e TimeSpan***. Com essas classes eu até consigo, mas sem poder utilizar elas por critério do professor não estou conseguindo fazer.
A imagem mostra como deve ficar o projeto, o restante eu já fiz, só falta mesmo verificar se a data que for digitada é valida ou não!
Alguém pode me dar alguma dica de como tentar resolver dessa forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você pode dividir a string do MaskedTextBox dando um split, utilizando a '/' como caractere, converter os números para inteiro e então validar.

> No `MaskedTextBox`, a propriedade `TextMaskFormat` deve estar como `IncludeLiterals` que é a configuração padrão.

Segue exemplo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string data = "31/03/2018"; //Aqui você coloca: seuMaskedTextBox.Text;

    int maiorAnoPermitido = 2050;
    int menorAnoPermitido = 2000;

    string[] val = data.Split('/');

    int dia, mes, ano;

    if (int.TryParse(val[0] , out dia) && int.TryParse(val[1], out mes) && int.TryParse(val[2], out ano))
    {
                if (ano >= menorAnoPermitido && ano <= maiorAnoPermitido)
                {
                    if (mes >=1 && mes <=12)
                    {

                        int maxDia = (mes==2 ? ( ano % 4 ==0 ? 29 : 28  ) : mes <=7 ? (mes%2==0?30 : 31) : (mes%2==0?31:30));                       

                        if (dia >=1 && dia <=maxDia)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Data Válida");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Dia inválido");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Mês inválido");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ano inválido");
                }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data inválida");
    }

}
```

Agora, com mais tempo, fiz a validação inclusive dos dias junto ao mês, além de definir variáveis para o maior e menor ano que o sistema deve aceitar.

Coloquei no .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTRN3k

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou mexer no código para ver o que eu consigo implementar, já deu uma esclarecida!

Comment: se o espertão q deu down puder aparecer e fazer a crítica, agradeço... imagino o motivo kkkk

Comment: @RovannLinhalis vivo tomando dessas :)

Comment: Só uma hipótese: pode ter sido porque o código acima permite datas inválidas (31 de fevereiro) e considera certas datas válidas como inválidas (i.e.: 01/01/1890).

Comment: a parte das datas inválidas, eu citei na resposta e basta incrementar as verificações, a parte de datas válidas como inválidas, acredito que fique a critério do programador, no cenário que ele está acredito que registrar uma informação de nome, cpf, email como data de entrada em 01/01/1890 seja inválido, basta ele definir quais anos serão válidos para o usuário inserir o registro @Renan

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Resolvi sim, obrigado!

Comment: @RovannLinhalis marquei

Answer (score 0):

Embora o objeto retornado pelo `Convert.ToDateTime` seja do tipo `DateTime`, não utilizou-se diretamente da classe `DateTime`... acho que poderia ser assim:

```
bool validaData;

try {
    Convert.ToDateTime(txtData.Text);
    validaData = true;
} catch (Exception exx) {
    validaData = false;
}

if(validaData){
    //Válida!
} else {
    //Não é válida!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter as porções do texto do campo e transformar em números:

```
string textoBruto = this.TextBoxN.Text;
int dia = Convert.ToInt32(textoBruto.Substring(0, 2), 10); // onde 10 significa base decimal
int mes = Convert.ToInt32(textoBruto.Substring(2, 2), 10);
int ano = Convert.ToInt32(textoBruto.Substring(4, 4), 10);
```

Suponho que as barras não fazem parte do texto... Não lembro como esse componente se comporta, mas se houver barras, é só tirar com um `Replace`.

E se essas conversões derem erro, é porque não eram inteiros válidos de qualquer forma.

Agora basta fazer duas verificações simples: se o mês está entre 1 e 12, e se os dias estão entre 1 e o máximo do mês.

```
if (mes < 1 || mes > 12) {
    throw new DataInvalidaMeuParsaException();
}
```

Uma dica pra pegar o maior dia possível do mês: você pode criar um hashmap, ou trapacear com um Array:

```
int[] maioresDias = new int[] {
    31,
    ano % 4 == 0 ? 29 : 28, // verificação de bissexto
    31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
};
```

E agora:

```
if (dia < 1 || dia > maioresDias[mes - 1]) {
    throw new ParaCeTaLokException();
}
```

P.s.: exceções meramente ilustrativas. .NET tem alguns tipos de exceção mais apropriados que já vem com ele, como `ArgumentException` ou `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver o que eu consigo fazer tendo uma ideia nas suas informações